# SQL Query Dividing a value from one table by correlating two separate units from two tables

Tags: sql

My database has every item in base units.
I have one table that has the quantity on hand in base units and the default purchasing unit.
I need to figure out how to divide the qty_on_hand by the default_purchasing_unit. Please help.

Table1

```
Item   Default_Purhcasing_Unit  Qty_On_Hand Base_Unit
=====  =======================  =========== =========
Item1  Box                      100         mL
```

Table2

```
Item   Unit_size  Unit_Of_Measure
=====  =========  ===============
Item1  1          mL
Item1  10         Box
Item1  100        Case
```

Desired result

```
Item   Qty_On_Hand 
=====  =========== 
Item1  10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need join tables by Item and UnitOfMeasure fields:

```
SELECT t1.Item, t1.Qty_On_Hand/t2.Unit_size AS Qty_On_Hand FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.Item=t2.Item AND t1.Default_Purchasing_Unit=t2.Unit_Of_Measure
```

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking for this answer for a year.